# Read TStream data in thread with Indy

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-7, indy, indy10

What is the proper way to create a thread that will read received data with IdTCPClient1 ? and all data are in TStream or Tmemorystream form.

I tried:

```
constructor TReadResponse.Create(AConn: TIdTCPConnection);
begin
  FConn := AConn;
  inherited Create(False);
end;

procedure TReadResponse.Execute;
var
  RcvStrMem : TMemoryStream;
begin
  while not Terminated and FConn.Connected do
  begin
    try
      RcvStrMem := TMemoryStream.Create;
      FConn.IOHandler.LargeStream := True;
      FConn.IOHandler.ReadStream(RcvStrMem, -1, False);//error here ??
      //MessageBox(0, pChar(inttostr(RcvStrMem.Size)), 0, 0);
      TWriteResponse.AddResponse(RcvStrMem);

    finally
      RcvStrMem.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

WriteResponse thread

```
class procedure TWriteResponse.AddResponse (AResponse: TStream);
begin
  with Create(AResponse) do try
  Synchronize;

  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TWriteResponse.DoSynchronize;
begin
 //do something
end;
```

Here's how I execute the thread in Form1:

```
var
    rr:   TReadResponse = nil;
......
procedure TForm1.IdTCPClient1Connected(Sender: TObject);
begin
 rr:=  TReadResponse.Create(IdTCPClient1);
end;
```

Comment: @iPath ツ: this code is **client-side**. `TIdTCPClient` is not a threaded component, so a manual thread is needed.  You are thinking of `TIdTCPServer` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I misread the question. Thanks for the hint. My comment is deleted.

Answer (score 2):

The code you showed is OK, provided that every TCP message is **preceded by an Int64, in network byte order, specifying the size of the message**, as that is what you are telling `ReadStream()` to read by setting `LargeStream=True`, `AByteCount=-1`, and `AReadUntilDisconnect=False`.  It will read 8 bytes and interpret them as an Int64, and then read however many bytes the Int64 says.

Since you did not provide any details about your actual TCP protocol, noone can tell you whether you are reading the TCP messages correctly or not. You said there is an error on the `ReadStream()`, but you did not say what the error actually is.  But the fact that you are getting an error suggests the TCP messages are NOT in the format that `ReadStream()` is expecting.

If you want more help, you need to show what the TCP messages actually look like.